# how to delete VBO correctly in python?

Tags: python, opengl, vbo, pyglet

I was wondering how to delete a vertex buffer object correctly in python. I generate my VBOs like this:

```
from ctypes import pointer
vbo_id = GLuint()
glGenBuffers(1, pointer(vbo_id))
```

From time to time I have to delete a VBO and create a new one instead. I was wondering what the **correct** way of deleting the VBO is? I've tried the following two ways but I don't know which one is correct (and python doesn't complain either way):

```
glDeleteBuffers(1, pointer(vbo_id))
or 
glDeleteBuffers(1, vbo_id)
```

Which call is correct? And does deleting the VBO also free the memory on the GPU?

Comment: seems like both ways are correct, since calling `glIsBuffer(vbo_id)` returns 0 in either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't write Python, so take it with that grain of salt, but the specification for `glDeleteBuffers()` takes a number of buffers and an array of buffer names. So it should probably be `pointer(vbo_id)`. In C, it's the same as `glGenBuffers()`, so I'd assume the same thing in Python. The reason being that the second parameter is an array of buffer names, not just a buffer name.

Comment: is there a way to check whether the VBO got deleted? I tried to call   `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id)` after the `glDeleteBuffers()` call but I don't get any error either.

Comment: You can call `glIsBuffer()` to see if it's been allocated already. I think that what you describe about not getting any errors has to do with some versions of OpenGL creating a buffer with that ID if it doesn't exist (which seems somewhat contrary to having to generate them first). But my memory on that is vague, so I could be mis-remembering.

Comment: @memyself: Note that if you just want to replace the data of the buffer you don't have to delete it, but you can simply reinitialize it with the new data using glBufferData.